# How to translate bool array from c++ to Python

Tags: c++, python-3.x, types

I am translating code from c ++ to python, I met with such a data type:

```
bool b[110];
```

How can this be translated into Python? I tried to do something, but in my opinion something is wrong here.

```
b = [False] * (110)
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Please remember that in Python, you **don't** need to pre-allocate data structures like lists.

Comment: What is your expected end result?

Comment: When I execute a function in c++, array `b` looks like this: `1110x55674af1c1a0`, but in Python: `[True, False, False,.....,False]`

Comment: Do you need the Python code to be **undefined behavior** compatible with the C++ code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see a difference between `bool b[110];` and `b = [False] * 110`.
Besides that `bool b[110];` only does "Garbage initialization" and python doesn't have anything even remotely similar to that.